# Default Lombok value for Jackson JsonSubTypes mapping

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I want to add boolean field called `negate` to this class.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@ApiModel
public class RelationEntityTypeFilter {

    @ApiModelProperty(position = 1, value = "Type of the relation between root entity and other entity (e.g. 'Contains' or 'Manages').", example = "Contains")
    private String relationType;

    @ApiModelProperty(position = 2, value = "Array of entity types to filter the related entities (e.g. 'DEVICE', 'ASSET').")
    private List<EntityType> entityTypes;

    @ApiModelProperty(position = 3, value = "Negate relation type between root entity and other entity.")
    private Boolean negate = false;
}
```

But I got NullPointer on `relationEntityTypeFilter.getNegate()`, when controller receives such JSON as `{ "relationType": "Contains", "entityTypes": []}`. In other words, `negate` field should be set to `false`, but this didn't happen

Here is `JsonSubTypes`

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SingleEntityFilter.class, name = "singleEntity"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EntityListFilter.class, name = "entityList"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EntityNameFilter.class, name = "entityName"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EntityTypeFilter.class, name = "entityType"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AssetTypeFilter.class, name = "assetType"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DeviceTypeFilter.class, name = "deviceType"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EdgeTypeFilter.class, name = "edgeType"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EntityViewTypeFilter.class, name = "entityViewType"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ApiUsageStateFilter.class, name = "apiUsageState"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RelationsQueryFilter.class, name = "relationsQuery"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AssetSearchQueryFilter.class, name = "assetSearchQuery"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DeviceSearchQueryFilter.class, name = "deviceSearchQuery"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EntityViewSearchQueryFilter.class, name = "entityViewSearchQuery"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = EdgeSearchQueryFilter.class, name = "edgeSearchQuery")})
public interface EntityFilter {

    @JsonIgnore
    EntityFilterType getType();
}
```

```
@Data
public class RelationsQueryFilter implements EntityFilter {

    @Override
    public EntityFilterType getType() {
        return EntityFilterType.RELATIONS_QUERY;
    }

    private EntityId rootEntity;
    private boolean isMultiRoot;
    private EntityType multiRootEntitiesType;
    private Set<String> multiRootEntityIds;
    private EntitySearchDirection direction;
    private List<RelationEntityTypeFilter> filters;
    private int maxLevel;
    private boolean fetchLastLevelOnly;

}
```

Comment: There is not limits in type. Is it an root cause? I understand that there are unit tests and manual testing, but there is a huge system and it is too long to deploy or add such test case.

Comment: Primitive `boolean` would be initialized to `false` by default (no extra actions required from you). In which forms `negate` property can come in JSON? Can you list all the cases?

Comment: Either `negate` will miss at all, or set to `false` as boolean JSON type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Boolean` as a field type doesn't buy you anything, wrapper types are useful for storing in a Collection, and other when you need a reference type (you simply can't use primitive as a generic type in Java, at least for). In all other cases, use a plain primitive `boolean`, it's much cleaner in the first place because it has only two possible values `false` and `true` (`false` is the default one).

If you change the type of `negate` from wrapper-type to primitive `boolean` it would be deserialized as `false` when the property is missing in the incoming JSON without any extra annotations.

Consider the following simplified class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public static class RelationEntityTypeFilter {
    private boolean negate;
}
```

Deserialization example:

```
String negateIsMissing = "{ }";
String negateIsFalse = """
    {
        "negate" : "false"
    }
    """;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
System.out.println(mapper.readValue(negateIsMissing, RelationEntityTypeFilter.class));
System.out.println(mapper.readValue(negateIsFalse, RelationEntityTypeFilter.class));
```

*Output:*

```
RelationEntityTypeFilter(negate=false)
RelationEntityTypeFilter(negate=false)
```